# Why doesn't the og:image show up?

Tags: image, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I share http://www.parler-de-sa-vie.net/ecrits/interviews/2012/giedre/, the og:image does not show up. Do you see any reason why?

Comment: You can not expect Facebook to display an image if your server answers the request for the exact og:image URL you have given with a 404 Not Found. http://www.parler-de-sa-vie.net/ecrits/interviews/2012/images/giedre_sa12_bsoula_270x180.jpg

Comment: You've got a point here CBroe. Thanks much for your answer, and shame on me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)